# Is there a GUI for configuring the Radeon Open Source Drivers and Mesa 3D similar to Catalyst Control Center?

Tags: graphics, software-recommendation, configuration, radeon, mesa

Is it possible to change the settings of the radeon open source drivers and Mesa 3D graphics library? I am thinking of something similar to Catalyst Control Center that would allow me to control settings such as:

- toggling VSYNC
- toggling framebuffering
- changing 3D acceleration
- changing aspect ratio / stretching to fit the screen
- changing power settings

FWIW, my graphics card is a Radeon HD 4350 (RV710) and I am running Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: see [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&section=all&arch=any&keywords=radeon+gui&searchon=all)

Comment: @DuminduMahawela Thanks, but none of these packages include a general purpose configuration utility for different graphical settings. I think I stumbled on a GUI for MESA at one point but I don't remember the name nor do I know if it's still available on 14.04.

Comment: What you are asking for does not exist.

Answer (score 8):

There are a few GUI tools available to control and monitor AMD open-source graphics under Linux but none of them are as easy to use or install as AMD's CCC:

1. **[DriConf](http://dri.freedesktop.org/wiki/DriConf/)** - GUI for controlling the direct rendering settings (OpenGL) of all open-source drivers. Pretty hard to use and hasn't been updated since 2006. [Phoronix has an overview and comparison to AMD's CCC](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTQ4NzQ).

   [image]

   DriConf can be found in the 'universe' repository of Ubuntu and can be downloaded from the Software Center:

   [image: Install via the software center]
2. **[radeon-profile](https://github.com/marazmista/radeon-profile)** - control power and clock settings on recent kernels (relies on new radeon dynamic power management). Documentation and support may be found in [this Phoronix thread](http://www.phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?83602-radeon-profile-tool-for-changing-profiles-and-monitoring-some-GPU-parameters)

   [image]

   [image]

   Unfortunately there aren't packages/PPAs available for radeon-profile. You will have to compile it manually.

Comment: DriConf is a very good suggestion. Actually it can be downloaded from the s/w center itself since it is in the 'universe' repository.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. CCC only works with the proprietary drivers (FGLRX). Please nore that this answer is about the open source graphics drivers for AMD cards (radeon/mesa). Driconf looks promising, though. Would you care to expand on what settings you can configure with Driconf? I think it would be important to know if the settings asked for in the question can be modified with this tool.

Comment: @Glutanimate I just downloaded DRIConf but I simply couldn't understand the options available in it!(I must confess i am not an expert in these kinda things.) So if you want i will post some screen shots and maybe you can understand it better.

Comment: @Venki No, it's fine. I mean, if you want to improve the answer, sure go ahead, but I was mainly addressing pgr with my last comment. I thought they might be familiar with driconf seeing how they suggested it.

Comment: @Glutanimate Right

Comment: OK after some research, driconf was the best what I can find in terms of gui. HOWEVER, changing many options requires editing text files which is quite complex, it's easy to destroy something and not easy to revert this changes but your options can be changed as far as i researched :)