# Adjust color temperature using GUI

Tags: color-management

I'm using a laptop with Ubuntu 14.04, using a external monitor I can adjust the color temp of the external monitor using its physical buttons in the monitor.

The question is, is there a way to adjust Brightness, Contrast. R,G,B slider with Ubuntu using a Graphical User interface, is there such a GUI for adjusting color temperature?

Comment: @Cornelius I don't think so, xybrek specifically asks for GUI.

Comment: If you are not using Nvidia/Ati, Not sure if DriConf has all needed settings. See [Is there a GUI for configuring the Radeon Open Source Drivers and Mesa 3D similar to Catalyst Control Center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/460926/is-there-a-gui-for-configuring-the-radeon-open-source-drivers-and-mesa-3d-simila)